# Can I use HOC programming style on a functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, modal-dialog

I have a class component that's empowered with the HOC withRouter, and connect() to have dispatch available in props

```
export default withRouter(connect()(MyComponent));
```

This component is coded as a class component, now, I changed the component to a functional component:

- Changed the function header from class "MyComponent expands..." to "const MyComponent = props => {..."
- Changed the way the state is created, by using "const [state, setState] = useState(..."
- Instead of coding componentDidMount to perform initial operations, I use

```
    useEffect(() => {
        getData()
    }, []);

    Where getData is:

    const getData = props => {
       const getDocument = async () => {
          const {
             dispatch,
             location: { search },     // Here I get an error, search and
             match: { params },        // params are undefined
          } = props;
       ...
    }
```

- Changed every function definition, from "handleSuccessAction = message => {..." to "const handleSuccessIndex = response => {..."
- Changed all reference to functions from "this.myFunction();" to "myFunction()"
- And leaved export default withRouter(connect()(MyComponent)) as is

**Begin EDIT:**

here is the whole code, once turned into a functional component

```
------------- all imports ------------------

const DocumentPreview = props => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        document: {
            documentType: '',
            name: '',
            file: {
                fileUrl: '',
                filename: ''
            },
        },
        file: {
            fileUrl: '',
            filename: ''
        },
     });

    useEffect(() => {
        getDocument();
    }, []);

    const getDocument = async () => {
        const {
            dispatch,
            location: { search },
            match: { params },
        } = props;
        const options = parseUrlParams(search);

        setState({ onRequest: true });
        showDocumentPreviewRequest(params.id, {
            employeeId: options.employee,
            dispatch,
            successCallback: handleSuccessIndex
        });
    };

    const handleSuccessIndex = response => {
        const { data } = response;
        const document = camelCaseRecursive(data);
        const file = document.fileInfo;

        setState({
            document,
            file,
            onRequest: false
        });
    };

    const { onRequest, document, file, modalBody, modalShow, modalTitle, defaultModalShow } = state;
    const { pendingToApprove, workflowRequest } = document;

    return (
        <>
------- Do my stuff -------------
        </>
    );
}

export default withRouter(connect()(DocumentPreview))
```

**End EDIT**

Why do I get this error?, am I doing it wrong?

I'm changing it to a functional component since I have to load the component on a modal, and as I won't be using router and render props, I think I can get this props by using hooks

Rafael

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: I can't include a minimal reproducible example since it is getting info from other components. What I'm going to do is to add the hole code, once turned into a functional component

Comment: `const getData = props =>` is possibly the problem, where the `props` from `getData` is shadowing the component's `props`, but it's unclear since the code snippet shared in your edit is different.

Comment: Hard to tell, but I'd suggest you move to using hooks instead of HOCs. React router and Redux both provide hooks.